# How do I alphabetize the items in two different CheckBoxLists?

Tags: c#, checkboxlist, alphabetized

I have two checkboxes (Recommended and Others) which have peoples names (concatenated, i.e. John Smith is one item).  I want to alphabetize the selected members of each list into one.  How can I do this?

Comment: Are these check boxes referencing business objects behind the scenes? or are they just holding names (ie. text)?

Comment: They are hooked up to SQL Data Sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ASP.NET implementation with three checkboxlist controls (chkRecommended, chkOthers, chkCombined)

```
var listItems = (from ListItem listItem in chkRecommended.Items
                 where listItem.Selected
                 select listItem)
                .Union(from ListItem listItem in chkOthers.Items
                       where listItem.Selected
                       select listItem)
                .OrderBy(listItem => listItem.Text);

chkCombined.Items.Clear();
foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
    chkCombined.Items.Add(listItem);
```

If you just meant a list of the values rather than another control, you can modify the original query I provided or extend it like so

```
var listValues = listItems.Select(listItem => listItem.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the selected members of both into a List of strings and sort, then put the list of strings into a new CheckBoxList.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx for the MSDN List(T).Sort Method example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're grabbing them from a SqlDataSource, why not do the alphabetizing via SQL?

Comment: Doesn't he want to alphabetize them after he has gotten them from SQL, once they are selected?